# Failed to install tower npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm getting to be failed to install tower npm.
Please let me know how to solve.

```
bash-3.2$ npm install -g tower
npm ERR! Darwin 15.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/ltcmdr927/.nvm/versions/node/v5.9.1/bin/node" "/Users/ltcmdr927/.nvm/versions/node/v5.9.1/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "tower"
npm ERR! node v5.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3

npm ERR! No compatible version found: tower-attr@~0.1.0
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! 0.1.0-pre
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/ltcmdr927/Workspaces/sandbox/npm-debug.log
```

My environment is:

```
bash-3.2$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.4
BuildVersion:   15E65
```

Modify: With sudo, same result:

```
bash-3.2$ sudo npm install -g tower
Password:
npm ERR! Darwin 15.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/ltcmdr927/.nvm/versions/node/v5.9.1/bin/node" "/Users/ltcmdr927/.nvm/versions/node/v5.9.1/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "tower"
npm ERR! node v5.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3

npm ERR! No compatible version found: tower-attr@~0.1.0
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! 0.1.0-pre
...
```

Anyone help?

Comment: try with `sudo npm install -g tower`

Comment: thx but it is same result with sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following command to install the source for **nodejs**

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo -E bash -
```

Then, run the following command to get the latest **nodejs** package

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

**Test It!**

Check if **Node** was installed

```
node -v
```

Check if the **npm** was installed

```
npm -v
```

**Installing tower**

```
npm install tower
```

To add this `npm` package to your local machine, run the above command  from your command line.

You’ll notice a **node_modules** directory appears in your root where the package was installed.

If you're having trouble installing packages, check out the helpful docs for [installing npm packages locally](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally)

Comment: Thanks, but it is same result with sudo.

Comment: Thanks, my environment is Mac OS X El Capitan and using nvm, but It was succeeded change nodejs version to v.0.10.43. commands: `nvm install v0.10.43`, `nvm alias default v0.10.43` and `npm install tower`.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands to remove all existing global npm modules, uninstall node & npm, re-install node with the right defaults, install npm as its own pacakge, and configure the location for global npm modules to be installed.

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
brew uninstall node
brew install node --without-npm
echo prefix=~/.npm-packages >> ~/.npmrc
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

Node and npm should be correctly installed at this point. The final step is to add ~/.node/bin to your PATH so commands you install globally are usable. I added this line to my ~/.path script, which gets run via ~/.bash_profile.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH"
```

Now you can re-install any global npm packages you need without any problems, Cheers.